# Twitter Bootstrap - nav bar issues in internet explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap in my rails app.  My navbar looks perfect in Firefox / Chrome / Safari (tested chrome on both a Mac & PC). In Internet Explorer, it looks *ugly*! Wrong colours & everything.

Any help you can provide would be appreciated. I can post whatever code would help.

### Update

Here is all of the CSS where I override anything from bootstrap (brought into my app via sass-rails gem). Hopefully it pushes us in the right direction.

Note: Where I have `color:#F8F8F8;` below, I used to have `#333`. This is just one iteration of me trying to fix it.  I've even tried changing the background color to `#333334` as I think that my precompiler was changing `#333333` to `#333` (don't know for sure though)

```
/*  Styling */

.navbar, .navbar-inner, .navbar-fixed-top, .container, #tabs .nav {
  border:none;
  background-image:none;
}

.navbar {

  font-size:14px;
  text-shadow:none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;

  .nav {
    float:right;
  }

  .brand {
    margin-left:30px;
    color:#333334;
    font-family: Georgia, serif
  }

  .navbar-inner {
      background-color: #F8F8F8;
      border-bottom-color: #E0E0E0;
      border-bottom-style: solid;
      border-bottom-width: 1px;
      color: #333334;
  }


}

.navbar .nav > li > a {
  text-shadow:none;
  color:#555555;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor:pointer;

  &:hover {
    color:#E6E6E6;
  }
}

.navbar .nav .active > a, .navbar .nav .active > a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #555555;
}

.navbar .nav .inactive > a:hover {
  color:#999999;
}

.navbar .nav > li > a.sign-in {
  color:#555555;
  padding-top:4px;
  padding-bottom:4px;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-left:30px;
}

.navbar .nav > li > a.sign-in:hover {

  background-position: 0 0px;

}

.navbar .nav > li > a.active-button {
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
  background-image: none;
  border:1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius:4px;
  box-shadow: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.6499999761581421;
  outline-color: #555555;
  outline-style: none;
  outline-width: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: none;
  padding-top:4px;
  padding-bottom:4px;
  margin-top:5px;
}
```

I have also tried the following (in an attempt to explicitly override anything to do with gradients from Bootstrap):

```
body {
  color:#333334;
}

.navbar-inner {
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F8F8F8, #F8F8F8);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F8F8F8, #F8F8F8);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#F8F8F8), to(#F8F8F8));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F8F8F8, #F8F8F8);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F8F8F8, #F8F8F8);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #F8F8F8, #F8F8F8);
}

.btn-navbar {
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F8F8F8, #F8F8F8);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F8F8F8, #F8F8F8);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#F8F8F8), to(#F8F8F8));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F8F8F8, #F8F8F8);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F8F8F8, #F8F8F8);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #F8F8F8, #F8F8F8);
}
```

**Yet another update**

Fiddling around with the internet explorer developer tools leads me to believe the issue is this:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FF333333',endColorstr='#F2222222', GradientType=0)
```

What is this?  Do I need it?  (Why does it not use the same gradients as firefox/chrome?)  It comes from Bootstrap... I can try to override the colours in there because for whatever reason IE is interpreting `FF333333` as that dark blue.

Comment: post some code so we can take a look.

Comment: Will throw up a bunch of relevant CSS... hope that helps!

Comment: @AndresIlich any thoughts?  Still struggling!

Comment: We need more info work with, the css you postd is not enough.

Comment: Try `filter:none` on your navbar (totally forgot about that), IE uses a separate syntax to generate gradients. `background-image` is still not supported by IE9 to create gradients.

Comment: So frustrating that something so small takes so long to fix! Thanks so much for your help.  Going to post an answer with the exact code I used to over-write the filter, but a HUGE rate-up for you!

Comment: I have identical code as yours, but I get the blue bar in production and a correct one in development.  I think the minification is confusing IE.

Comment: I got this problem when I used stylebootstrap.info, which is a great tool other than it caused the problem you describe below in your solution.

Comment: What file in bootstrap has the offending line 'filter:progid...'?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Turns out I was able to fix this by over-riding the default filter code generated by Bootstrap.  Big thanks for Nathan and Andres!  To override the code I had posted above, I added the following :

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#F8F8F8', endColorstr='#F8F8F8', GradientType=0)
```

Hope this saves some pain for somebody....

Comment: You helped me save a ton of pain. Apparently I had the line:
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#'ffffff, endColorstr='#'e5e5e5, GradientType=0);, where the ' quotes only enclosed the '#' sign and not the whole color. Changing it to, for example '#ffffff' made it work.

Comment: I was still experiencing this with Bootstrap 2.1.0 using dotless, and it turns out the problem was dotless.  Since that's been updated to 1.3.1.0 the problem has gone away (dotless is formatting the colours in filters correctly for IE)

Comment: I think there is a slightly better answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088485/replace-background-in-twitter-bootstrap-navbar-for-ie

Answer (score 14):

Andres Ilich commented on the OP:

> "Try `filter:none` on your navbar (totally forgot about that), IE uses a
>   separate syntax to generate gradients. `background-image` is still not
>   supported by IE9 to create gradients."

After developing very painful forehead from smacking it numerous times on the desk, this is exactly what fixed the issue for me. Thanks Andres.

Comment: I really think they should have made the default CSS a little less involved. For a framework that's supposed to help speed up web development, they sure make it a pain to style. Is that minor gradient really so important to the default style that they need to add so much complexity to the customization of the primary navigation?

Comment: THANK YOU, you saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me too. But I found out that in CSS gradients, IE (even 9) doesn't seem to except just 3-character HEX codes. So you need to change the hex codes  to 3-character instead if they aren't already (such as `#CCC` to `#CCCCCC`) so it'll work correctly in IE (only for the IE gradient CSS, not all of them).

If you could post your CSS I could see if there are any other problems. But, my problem was that `#CCC` was being interpreted as dark blue in IE.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  I'll give that a shot!

Comment: Unfortunately still can't get it to work (managed to get it to go somewhat black...) Will post some code.

Comment: @Brandon That's weird. Mine was all blue and ugly looking like yours (actually it looked exactly like yours) but I changed it to the longer version and it worked. How does it look in IE now?

Comment: unfortunately its still terrible looking... will post an updated capture.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: @brandon - have you tried setting it to black and white temporarily to see if that works? Also is the CSS that you posted all for the header or is there more? If so please post that as well.

Comment: I just used -ms-filter: etc etc (vendor prefixes) and this solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

From what i can tell you're using a solid color for your background in the top navbar, so you're only adding a background-color but not removing the background-image as well, so try to reset that too like so:

```
  .navbar-inner {
      background-color: #F8F8F8;
      background-image:none;
      border-bottom-color: #E0E0E0;
      border-bottom-style: solid;
      border-bottom-width: 1px;
      color: #333334;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is much more simple:

```
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, 
.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, 
.dropdown-submenu:hover>a, 
.dropdown-submenu:focus>a,
.dropdown-menu>li.active>a
{
   filter: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer is quite good at messing things up what I normally do is use a separate style sheet to fix up explore without messing up the rest of my site. Paste this line of code in your web pages:

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/fix_internet_explore.css">
<![endif]-->
```

and modify the css to make look better on explorer, and the good part is other browsers will ignore this style sheet.