# Replace background in Twitter Bootstrap navbar for IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, background-image, navbar

I am trying to replace the background image for a Twitter Bootstrap navbar with my own image. It works in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari but not in Internet Explorer. What am I missing for IE? (It remains the plain black in IE)

```
.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-inner {
    background: url(/assets/navbar.png) repeat-x;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to add this:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
```

Comment: wow, thank you so much! WTF is that even doing? I've never seen it before.

Comment: You're welcome! The code in my answer is just disabling the gradient that was set by Bootstrap. The "Use CSS3, not DX Filters" section of [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/12/07/moving-to-standards-based-web-graphics-in-ie10.aspx) has a good description of DX Filters.

Comment: `filter:none` solved for me, as pointed out [here](http://www.anujgakhar.com/2012/09/05/twitter-bootstrap-navbar-color-in-ie89/).